# How to add custom prefix and suffix string in a field in solr

Tags: solr

Like the title said I tried many ways to add a prefix and/or a suffix in a field in solr. More precisely I mean:

For example I have those fields in my schema.xml

```
field name="field1" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"

field name="field2" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"
```

I would like to have my third field like this

```
"field3" = "{a prefix}field1 field2{a suffix}
```

The problem is, I saw many ways to copy field or concat other store fields 
but I don't want my prefix or my suffix be stored in solr, I just want to have a field3 with two other fields and custom strings that I choose to put in. I ask this question here because after a lot of search I did not find anything good for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html) to manipulate the contents of the field on the way in, and merge it with the values from field1 and field2.

As you can write regular Javascript in the script referenced from the processor, you can add the prefix and suffix in any way you want, without having to supply it in the request.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply, i will try this and will tell you if it works fine for me